# AngularJS: Prevent function from firing when clearing input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have an AngularJS 1.7x app with "instant" search functionality that executes a search function after a 500ms  delay and as long as there are at least 3 characters (code below).

The problem is after I perform a search and then hit the reset button.  Everything resets like it's supposed to, but when I go to enter a new query the ng-minlength is no longer honored - i.e. the query function is called even if I've only entered a single character.

The resulting error comes from the fact that $scope.searchParams.q is no longer availably in the request body on the second (accidental) POST.

Here is the View:

```
<input ng-model="searchQuery" ng-change="query(searchQuery)" ng-minlength="3"
 ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {default:500, blur:0}}">

<md-button ng-if="searchQuery" ng-click="reset()">Clear</md-button>
```

Here is the relevant functions in the controller:

```
$scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.searchQuery = null;
    $scope.searchParams.selectedCity = [];
    $scope.searchParams.q = [];
    $scope.searchResults = {};
};

$scope.query = function (searchText) {
    $scope.searchParams.q = searchText;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: $rootScope.url,
        data: $scope.searchParams
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {                                
        $scope.searchResults = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $rootScope.errorToast()
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it fires is that searchText is no longer null, instead is just empty.
Try to add *if(searchText.length>=3)* at the begining of your query function